# BigQuery | bq load with inline schema with STRING REPEATED

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to load a bq table with the below definition and one of the column (ref_list) is of **STRING REPEATED**.

```json
[
  {
    "name": "emp",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "ref_list",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "name": "update_date",
    "type": "DATE"
  }
]
```

**Below is how my input data is**:

```json
{"emp":"Adam","ref_list":["Roger","Calvin","Andrew","Kohl"],"update_date":"1999-01-01"}
{"emp":"AntiP27","ref_list":["John","Patrick","Nick","Chris"],"update_date":"2020-01-01"}
```

I am able to load the table by point the .schema file from my local but the same is failing when I provide the in-line schema.

Here is my bq load command with inline schema option. I am not quite sure how I could specify the mode = REPEATED

```
bq load --replace --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON emp_stage.emp_dtl gs://1324-global-delivery/emp_dtl.json emp:STRING,ref_list:STRING,update_date:DATE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, it's not possible to specify a `RECORD` and the columns `mode` (NULLABLE, REPEATED), with an inline schema :

> When you specify the schema on the command line, you cannot include a
> RECORD (STRUCT) type, you cannot include a column description, and you
> cannot specify the column's mode. All modes default to NULLABLE. To
> include descriptions, modes, and RECORD types, supply a JSON schema
> file instead.

[bq_manually_specifying_schemas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#manually_specifying_schemas)

If you need to use these parameters, you have to specify them in a `Json` schema in a dedicated file, as you used in your example.